# OM-D M5 Firmware update does not install

Tags: olympus, firmware, olympus-omd

I can't update the firmware of my OM-D M5 to the latest release 1.7. That's what I tried:

1. Start the firmware update tool (Ver 1.06 on OSX Mavericks),
2. Connect the camera to a USB port of my Mac and turn it on
3. The camera displays a "USB" menu. Select "Storage" and press OK
4. Screen shows "one moment", then goes blank
5. On the Mac, Aperture starts and wants to import images
6. Switch back to the firmware update tool and click "Next"
7. After a while, it shows current version 1.6, newer version 1.7 for the body
8. Make sure that the "body" line is selected and click "update", and confirm twice
9. "Updating firmware" is shown on the computer for a while.
10. Finally, it says that the camera screen should display an image with rotating arrows and two "forbidden" signs, which indicates that the firmware is being updated.

However the camera screen stays blank. I waited several minutes, no change. If I disconnect the camera, turn it off and on again, and check the firmware version, it is still 1.6.

N.B., the same procedure worked correctly when updating the firmware of two different lenses.

How can I update the firmware?

Comment: Do you have a windows PC somewhere to try if it works there?

Comment: No, but I tried again, see below...

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer as the "correct" one, so other stackexchange visitors can see this question has a valid answer?

Comment: @he1ix did this work for you as well?

Comment: I didn't do the update yet, so I don't know. Still, as long as there is no indicator that something else was the reason, I'd suggest to accept it - I had almost overlooked it initially ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After I replaced the 64GB SD card that I'm normally using with a 1 GB card, the update worked.

Go figure...

Comment: I don't know whether this is really the reason that it worke this time, or something else

Comment: Just updated from firmware 2.0 to 2.1 using a 32 GB SD card. So either the magic boundary is between 32 and 64 GB, or some update fixed the limitation with larger cards